Flutter check if url has '/' at the end
In flutter I need concatenate server and file addresses. The problem is that server address may not contain '/' at the end. What is the best way to check and solve it? Now I am doing like this:
String server = "http(s)://www.someaddress.com/"
addFile(server);

addFile() declared like this:
Uri addFile(String address)
{

   if(address.isNotEmpty && !address.endsWith('/'))
   {
     address += '/';
   }

   Uri uri = Uri.parse("${address}myfile.txt");

   return uri;
 }

Edited:
  String server = "http(s)://www.someaddress.com/somepath"


Use Uri's built in ability to manipulate its component parts. You can combine with the path package to specifically manipulate parts of the URI's path.
import 'package:path/path.dart';

void main() {
  print(append(Uri.parse('https://www.someaddress.com'), 'myfile.txt'));
  print(append(Uri.parse('https://www.someaddress.com/'), 'myfile.txt'));
  print(append(Uri.parse('https://www.someaddress.com/foo'), 'myfile.txt'));
  print(append(Uri.parse('https://www.someaddress.com/foo/'), 'myfile.txt'));
}

Uri append(Uri server, String filename) {
  final context = Context(style: Style.posix);
  // replace the path with the existing path joined with the filename
  return server.replace(path: context.join(server.path, filename));
}

Using replace you can modify any part. Note that this code works with a server URI with or without a trailing slash, and with or without an existing path.
The above code prints:
https://www.someaddress.com/myfile.txt
https://www.someaddress.com/myfile.txt
https://www.someaddress.com/foo/myfile.txt
https://www.someaddress.com/foo/myfile.txt


Thanks for your answer, probably I was not that correct - server address may include also a path like this: "http(s)://www.someaddress.com/somepath/". And in this case the path is being replaced.

See updated answer. If you wanted to use this frequently you could make it an extension to Uri.
